# iOS 14 crash in NSFetchedResultsController's indexPathForObject function

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, ios14

I've been facing a crash on iOS 14 onwards on using NSFetchedResultsController.

**Precondition:**

I'm using NSFetchRequest to initialise NSFetchedResultsController and in fetch request I'm using propertiesToFetch to fetch a single property, resultType as NSDictionaryResultType with returnsDistinctResults as YES for getting distinct results. Below is the fetch request used for NSFetchedResultsController object.

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([ABC class])];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id = %@ AND removed = NO",
                         [LMSAppDelegate sharedDelegate].module.cycleID];
    request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
    request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"xyz"];
    request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"xyz" ascending:YES]];

    return request;
}
```

NSFetchedResultsController is used as a data source for a table in our application.

**Problem:**

This was working fine in below iOS 14 versions, but it's started to crash for iOS 14 and and above(14.1), the reason for the same is that the dictionary we pass to get the index path in function 'indexPathForObject' is failing to return the index path with exception unrecognised selector(logs attached). Below function is crashing.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForObject:(id)object {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:object];
}
```

I did not found any document or a new API which can be used for the same purpose.

Please let me know how I can resolve this issue.

```
Stack Trace:

2020-10-27 11:50:22.165740+0530 XYZ[70020:1505717] -[__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600007efeb80
2020-10-27 11:50:22.245891+0530 XYZ[70020:1505717] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600007efeb80'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b681126 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b511f78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b68fc6f +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b685666 ___forwarding___ + 1489
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b687698 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreData                            0x00000001051e3f23 -[_NSDefaultSectionInfo indexOfObject:] + 80
    6   CoreData                            0x000000010533671d -[NSFetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:] + 151
    7   Lido_mPilot                         0x0000000101ed4ac3 -[LMSFetchedResultsDataSource indexPathForObject:] + 99
    8   Lido_mPilot                         0x000000010238b1dc -[LMSFleetTableViewDataSource indexPathForObject:] + 140
    9   Lido_mPilot                         0x0000000101e160ad -[LMSFleetTableViewController viewWillAppear:] + 365
    10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000122115fb2 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 654
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001221167db -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 106
    12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000122047534 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 726
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000122048371 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 851
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00000001220496dc -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000122029f1e -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 217
    16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000122d9c9ce -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2874
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00000001099e9d87 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 258
    18  QuartzCore                          0x00000001099f0239 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 575
    19  QuartzCore                          0x00000001099fbf91 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 65
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010993c078 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 496
    21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000109972e13 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 783
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00000001228701a3 _afterCACommitHandler + 164
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5ee6b3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5e8f3f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 547
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5e94e2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1113
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b5e8b9e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e2e3db3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    28  UIKitCore                           0x000000012283faf3 -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    29  UIKitCore                           0x0000000122844a04 UIApplicationMain + 101
    30  Lido_mPilot                         0x0000000102421ce1 main + 193
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cf64415 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600007efeb80'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.17 - Device: iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (FE6E057B-B3C6-495D-9305-182325E6C237) - Runtime: iOS 14.0 (18A372) - DeviceType: iPad Pro (9.7-inch)
```

Thank You

Comment: It would help if you shared the relevant code.

Comment: @RobertCrabtree Although the question was quite straight forward, I've added some code for better understanding, it is the same code working in iOS vesrions < 14.0, apple API is broken in 14.0 and above for above code.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue: works in iOS 13.7 and below, not in iOS 14+. Just a simple `indexPath(forObject:)` call. I'm not making the call in a notification and it's running in the main thread, I can't figure it out...